# How to include the Google Play Services RSA public key in my Android app binary?

Tags: android, google-play-services

First, I am an iOS developer. I am not Android expert. I need maintain one Android App project. About the app signing issue, the rules between iOS and Android are so different!

At the moment, I know how to sign my Android app and publish it on Google play.

**BUT**, I found this in Google play Developer Console -> my app ->Services & APIs:

[image]
They given me this public key.

**My Question** is:
How to, and where to use this public key? I have signed my app already by ADT's wizard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an optional use item, if you want to use it to enforce licensing requirements on a per app basis take a look here [Google licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)

Basically, this is a a system to allow for your app to check the Google Servers with the public key, and determine (based on the response) how your apps behavior should continue (or not).

If you are not concerned with applying licensing restrictions, then it is absolutely not required in your final apk.